# Nginx is redirection to localhost:8080 after userlogin to website

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I am using nginx server and tomcat for that I am using following configuration

```
server {
  listen          80;
  root            /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT;
   server_name    ssss.com;
   server_name_in_redirect off;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sss/site_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sss/site_error.log debug;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

my problem is aftr user (give userid and password) login process my url is shoing localhost:8080/Home.

here Home is correct but insted of localhost:8080 that should be my site name.

How to resolve this.

Comment: try `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: should i remove ` proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thanks alot this is perfect

Answer (score 4):

I assume your webapplication is running on tomcat on localhost:8080. So what you are looking for is to use nginx as a proxy in front of the running tomcat instance. I conducted a small test with an absolute minimum configuration on my linux dev box here. You can use the following configuration with nginx:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  }
}
```

**Please note, that this is not for production use!**

Please consider e.g. the [nginx webpage](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/) on how to secure your nginx configuration / proxy settings.

Comment: do you mind accepting the answer, if it solved your problem?